Cointersections in a category
I'm reading Grillet's account on regular categories in the "Exact Categories" book. In the introduction, he says he will consider intersections and cointersections:

What is the definition of intersection and cointersection in a general category?

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/intersection

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

You should not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. See here for why.

The intersection of a family of subobjects is the largest subobject that factors through all of them, or more concretely the limit (assuming it exists) of the diagram formed by a representative of each subobject, as for instance the pullback of $f:A\to X\leftarrow B:g$ for the intersection of the subobjects $f,g.$ The cointersection is the dual operation, taking a colimit of quotient maps.

Be careful in which category you take the pullback. In general, the intersection is not the pullback in the ambient category. It is just a (wide) pullback in the category of subobjects.

@MartinBrandenburg I'm missing your point somehow. An intersection is a product in the category of (i.e. whose objects are) subobjects, which for two subobjects is the same as the pullback in the underlying category. Ah, I guess you're worried about the case where the pullback might not exist, right? Sure, fair enough.

No, that is not the point. The point is that the inclusion functor from subobjects of X to the slice category over X doesn't necessarily preserve products. So extra care is necessary when speaking of "pullbacks", which usually refer to products in the slice category.

In other words, if U,V are subobjects of an object X, and W is their intersection, it is not necessarily true that a morphism from Y to X that factors through U and V also factors through W. This is only known when the morphism is a monomorphism. So in particular W doesn't have to be the pullback of U and V in the ambient category.

Huh. Is the nLab then wrong to claim that "In a finitely complete category, the intersection of two monomorphisms $A \hookrightarrow X$ and $B \hookrightarrow X$ can be computed by a pullback of the cospan $A \to X \leftarrow B$"?

@MartinBrandenburg It does seem to me that I'm making the same point as you, with the addition that, if the pullback in the ambient category exists, then it will compute the intersection. This is how intersections are almost always calculated in practice which is why I and the nLab both made the statement thus imprecisely.

@NaïmFavier It's correct because the nLab also assumes the category is finitely complete. If the pullback in question exists, it always computes the intersection.

When you say "quotient maps", are you referring to the quotient objects of congruences on $X$ (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quotient+object)?

@LazarusFrost Just arbitrary epimorphisms out of $X$ for the perfect duality with subobjects, although certainly in many categories the more interesting quotient objects will be strong, regular, or effective epis.
